# NodeJs: Get output of python-shell to send back to client

Tags: python, node.js

I am trying to create a website where a user can submit python code, it gets sent to my server to be executed and I send back the results to the client. Currently I am using a NodeJs server and need to run the python code from there. To do this, I am using Python-shell like so:

```
const runPy = async (code) => {
   const options = {
      mode: 'text',
      pythonOptions: ['-u'],
      scriptPath: path.join(__dirname, '../'),
      args: [code],
   };

  const result = await PythonShell.run('script.py', options, (err, results) => {
     if (err) throw err;
     return results; <----- HOW DO I RETURN THIS
  });
  console.log(result.stdout);
  return result;
};
```

I understand I can `console.log()` the results in the `PythonShell.run()` but is there a way to return the results from my `runPy` function to then be manipulated and sent back to the client?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks from the `python-shell` documentation that the `PythonShell.run` method doesn't have an async mode. So, one option is to wrap it in a promise:

```js
const runPy = async (code) => {
   const options = {
      mode: 'text',
      pythonOptions: ['-u'],
      scriptPath: path.join(__dirname, '../'),
      args: [code],
   };

  // wrap it in a promise, and `await` the result
  const result = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    PythonShell.run('script.py', options, (err, results) => {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      return resolve(results);
    });
  });
  console.log(result.stdout);
  return result;
};
```